# How to update url in browser when content is loaded through ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, url

In my webapp i am loading images in fancybox. Now i want that when images are opened, URL of browser changes as if new page has loaded,and points to locaion of image eg:
If siteurl is:

```
http://mysite.org
```

when image is loaded using ajax then it should show:

```
http://mysite.org/imag1.jpg
```

It is helpful because users are able to refer to images using url.I can fetch url using ajax or by any other method, but how can I update browser url to point to that location.It will be great if back and forward buttons can switch switch back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [HTML5 history API](http://html5demos.com/history).

Edit: [This tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) seems to be good. There are a few examples in this tutorial.

Comment: I searched for html 5 history api, examples I found were little bit though for me, can you suggest some easy to understand example for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax callback, you could:

```
window.location.href = 'http://mysite.org/imag1.jpg';
```